# Puzzle tableview with tableviewcell...?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, xcode4

I have a small query.I have made an application in which i am fetching information from the webservice and i am displaying it on the table view.The table view which i a using is customized one in which i have used the text and the image property.
These things are working fine but now i have added a button ,once i click on it then a new view appears which has 2 options for 2 countries whose webservices are provided to me ,once i click on one button and see the table view then the list of the previous table view only appears and if i scroll through the whole list then the values changes which is according to the webservice.

So kindly suggest me as in what should be the approach of directly showing the updated tablecells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

call it explicitly from the secon view, or you can put it in viewWillAppear